# RVM permission denied on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-11.10

I've been through all tutorials and solved problems I can find about RVM. There's something wrong with permissions. There are no rubies installed, and when I try to install one: "permission denied". I can't even do **rvm implode** without "permission denied".

Comment: apt-get messed it up, it forced a rvm_path to /usr/share, because I did it with sudo.

Solution:
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm && sudo apt-get purge ruby-rvm

Comment: i think what you are after is rvmsudo:  under multi user installs (when you install as root) http://beginrescueend.com/support/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my detailed answer to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395

There were few attempts to fix the ubuntu package - but nobody had enough time to finish it.